# Is it possible to extract some particular directory from a .tgz?

Tags: php

I downloaded a big .tgz thanks to the `file_put_contents` method but I'm only interested in for some files/directories from this .tgz.

I planned to use the `PharData::extractTo` and `PharData::decompress` methods in order to get its content but they extract all the files.

Is there a way to extract the precise files/directories I want or do I have to extract all the files ?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`phar://` stream wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.stream.php) to access the content of an individual file of an archive, see the examples on [Using Phar Archives: the Phar and PharData class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.object.php) :

> ```
> <?php
> // these two calls to file_get_contents() are equivalent if
> // /path/to/myphar.phar has an explicit alias of "myphar.phar"
> // in its manifest, or if the phar was initialized with the
> // previous example's Phar object setup
> $f = file_get_contents('phar:///path/to/myphar.phar/whatever.txt');
> $f = file_get_contents('phar://myphar.phar/whatever.txt');
> ?>
> ```

As an example, the following code

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('phar://test.tar/test.sql'));
```

might generate the following output:

```
string(94) "INSERT INTO Users(Username) VALUES ('abc');
SELECT * FROM Users;
CREATE TABLE dummy (id INT);
"
```